# get value of node behind the pointer in a singly non circular linkedlist

Tags: c++, c, list, linked-list

Question: 
Linkedlist = a,b,c,d,e = node1, node2, node3, node4, node5

I am on 5th node and want to get value of 2nd node (value = `b`). I traversed and didnt saved the value of 2nd node. Now I am at 5th node. Cant go back or start again.

What ways do I have?

---

its a c++ `singly non-circular linked list`  where I **cant go back or move in circular** direction,  node 1,2,3,4,5

If I am on node 5, can I make the 2nd node as tail ( I was on tail = 5 ) before ?) <- can I do that while still being on 5 and not going back or forward ?  I just want to get the value of 2nd node by any means. I was thinking that, some how, I  can put 5th behind 2nd or  put 2nd after 5th. then move one step forward. ( as I can go forward but not back). then get value of 2nd node.

IF I KNOW that there are 5 elements. cant I just make the `b` element as tail.    at this moment, I would be on the 4th `e` (which would no longer be  the tail) then I can move forward to the 5th element `b` (which was not present until I made the 2nd element become the 5th element)

Comment: You always have the head of the list, so you will just have to iterate from there to get to the node that you want.

Comment: reiteration is not an option

Comment: "Cant go back or start again." - yes. game over.

Comment: cant we change the head / tail?

Comment: head, tail? are you speaking about a single-linked list or what are you talking about?

Comment: can you give a concrete example? it would be easier to show you on that how you handle such cases.

Answer (score 1):

This is generally speaking not possible, because a singly-linked non-circular list, *by definition*, has no back pointers. The only **reliable** way to find the second element is to start from the first element.

Comment: It sounds like your "reputable seniors" may not be so reputable after all.

Comment: singly linked list can have more that 1 pointers? i think if we make 2 pointers with a gap of 3 nodes between them. we can do it?

Comment: You can always remember previous values, if you *want*. if you didn't there's nothing you can do now.

Comment: Searching all of memory would not only be fragile, it would also be more expensive than just iterating from the head of the list

Comment: Masood, I gues you wrote us wrong parameters of task (if it has to be possible to solve it), or you understood task wrong.

Searching over memory is good solution if list is vector and holds members in one block, other way that is not solution, I guess.

Comment: @PaulR, I am giving him *an* answer which matches his requirements. His requirements do not seem to include efficiency or reasonability. :P

Comment: what about making 2 pointers? is it possible? i think if we make 2 pointers with a gap of 3 nodes between them. we can do it?

Comment: -1. *"search all of memory"* - **don't**. ever. not portable and not reliable (false positives).

Comment: @MasoodAhmad, You can add whatever pointers you want into your structure, but your definition of Linked list would have to change.

Comment: so it would not be a singly linked list any more?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, I added all the caveats. If you really don't like it, please edit the answer and delete everything after the first paragraph.

Comment: @merlin2011: ok, I will.

Comment: so lastly, I am assuming that I am on 5th node, I traversed. Now the code further continues. If I am on the 5th node, I add one more pointer on the 2nd node. I can get its value?

Comment: @MasoodAhmad, Yes, if you happen to have made a pointer to the 2nd node and stored it in the 5th node, then you can get the value of the 2nd node.

Answer (score 1):

That *bad news* is that you can't do anything. It's game over. It's like asking in chess what the best move would be when you already got checkmated.

The *good news* is, whatever programming task you do (well, as long as it's solvable by a turing machine), there's a way to code it to prevent that you ever get such a position.

*Remember* the 2nd element, or remember the root, and then you'll always be able to access it. Some algorithms remember recent(previous) elements, e.g. that's how you can delete a node from a single linked list.